# Fancybox: disable right click

Tags: javascript, fancybox, dreamweaver

I need help with disable right click on fancybox. I can't get it to work. Please help with finding a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding : 0
});
```

To disable right click, I have to add this script:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            /* Disable right click */
            $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If it's `How to disable right click on fancybox?` then you seem to be answering it with the second code block...

Comment: I know I have the code to disable right click but it is not working.  It doesn't disable my images on fancy box. I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you want to prevent with disabling right click? Image stealing? There are plenty of other ways they can get a copy of your images **without** even using the mouse.

Comment: yeah to prevent image stealing...what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Comment: The easiest way to prevent a user from stealing your image(s) is to not show them to the user at all. As long as they can see it on the page, they can steal it. Best case scenario, they look at your page's source and find the link referencing the image file, worst case scenario, they screenshot it. Either way, they have your image, so if you're so desperate about protecting your image, then perhaps displaying it on a website is not a safe option. **Highly suggest reading: http://css-tricks.com/techniques-for-fighting-image-theft/**

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful ==> No.3

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".fancybox").bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

to prevent right click on the element with class fancybox. Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtvnpfv2/)

Comment: Strange, because it does on the div in the JSFiddle, do you get any errors in the console that could help us?

Comment: I figured out. This works: $('body').on('contextmenu', 'img', function(e){     return false; });